# Gostaria de saber oque está de errado no meu código?

Tags: c++

O meu código é de uma pergunta, estou aprendendo a programar e usando o site [codcad](http://www.codcad.com), a pergunta está na imagem. Quando eu envio o meu código, ele somente da 60 pontos de 100. Eu gostaria de saber oque eu estou fazendo de errado.

Segue a imagem.

Edit:Tentei resolver a questão usando somente oque eu aprendi no site, coisas mais avançadas ainda não sei muito bem, por isso posso ter ido por uma logica mais complicada.[image: Questão]

> **Questão** obs:A questão está relacionada a uma lista de exercícios sobre if.   Carnaval (OBI 2012, Fase 2, Nível 1)
>
> O Carnaval é um feriado celebrado normalmente em fevereiro; em muitas
>   cidades brasileiras, a principal atração são os desfiles de escolas de
>   samba. As várias agremiações desfilam ao som de seus sambas-enredos e
>   são julgadas pela liga das escolas de samba para determinar a campeã
>   do Carnaval.
>
> Cada agremiação é avaliada em vários quesitos; em cada quesito, cada
>   escola recebe cinco notas que variam de 5,0 a 10,0. A nota final da
>   escola em um dado quesito é a soma das três notas centrais recebidas
>   pela escola, excluindo a maior e a menor das cinco notas.
>
> Como existem muitas escolas de samba e muitos quesitos, o presidente
>   da liga pediu que você escrevesse um programa que, dadas as notas da
>   agremiação, calcula a sua nota final num dado quesito.
>
> Entrada A entrada contém uma única linha, contendo cinco números Ni(1≤
>   i ≤5), todos com uma casa decimal, indicando as notas recebidas pela
>   agremiação em um dos quesitos.
>
> Saída Seu programa deve imprimir uma única linha, contendo um único
>   número com exatamente uma casa decimal, a nota final da escola de
>   samba no quesito considerado.
>
> Restrições
>   5.0 ≤Ni ≤10.0
>
> ```
> **Exemplos de Entrada**    ......     *Exemplos de Saída*  
> **6.4 8.2 8.2 7.4 9.1**        ......     *23.8*  
> **10.0 10.0 5.0 5.0 10.0**     ......     *25.0*
> ```

**Código**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

 double a, b, c, d, e;

 cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;

 if (a>=b and a>=c and a>=d and a>=e){
    if(b<a and b<=c and b<=d and b<=e){
        cout<<c+d+e;
     }
     if(c<b and c<=d and c<=e) {
        cout<<b+d+e;
     }
     if(d<=b and d<c and d<=e){
        cout<<b+c+e;
     }
    if(e<a and e<b and e<c and e<d){
        cout<<b+c+d;
     }
 }
 if (b>a and b>=c and b>=d and b>=e){
    if(a<b and a<=c and a<=d and a<=e){
        cout<<c+d+e;
    }
    if(c<a and c<=d and c<=e){
        cout<<a+d+e;
    }
    if (d<a and d<c and d<=e){
        cout<<a+c+e;
    }
    if(e<a and e<b and e<c and e<d){
        cout<<a+c+d;
    }
 }
 if (c>a and c>b and c>=d and c>=e){
    if(a<=b and a<=d and a<=e){
        cout<<b+d+e;
    }
    if(b<a and b<=d and b<=e){
        cout<<a+d+e;
    }
    if(d<a and d<b and d<=e){
        cout<<a+b+e;
    }
    if(e<a and e<b and e<c and e<d){
        cout<<a+b+d;
    }
 }
 if(d>a and d>b and d>c and d>=e){
    if(a<=b and a<=c and a<=e){
        cout<<b+c+e;
    }
    if(b<a and b<=c and b<=e){
        cout<<a+c+e;
    }
    if(c<a and c<b and c<=e){
        cout<<a+b+e;
    }
    if(e<a and e<b and e<c and e<d){
        cout<<a+b+c;
    }
 }
 if(e>a and e>b and e>c and e>d){
    if(a<=b and a<=c and a<=d){
    cout<<b+c+d;
    }
    if(b<a and b<=c and b<=d){
    cout<<a+c+d;
    }
    if(c<a and c<b and c<=d){
    cout<<b+a+d;
    }
    if(e<a and e<b and e<c and e<d){
        cout<<a+b+c;
    }

 }
}
```

obs: Me desculpem por qualquer coisa que eu tenha feito de errado sou novo no site e se eu estiver feito algo de errado aceito sugestões e dicas.
obs2: Aceito dicas e sugestões tbm para questão de programação. 
Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Olá Prometheus. A lógica não precisa ser tão complicada assim. Leia as 5 notas para um `vector`, ordene-as (e.g., usando [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)) e some os três elementos do meio.

Comment: Verifique também que sua saída sempre possui uma casa decimal:  `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << somaNotas;`

Comment: Me desculpe faltou informações na minha pergunta, essa sua dica pelo que pesquisei deve resolver, mais sou bem novato em programação e se for possível me dar uma explicação mais simples ficaria grato, pois usei tudo que sei até o momento.

Comment: Um bom começo seria postar o enunciado em texto, e não um print de tela.

Comment: okay, achei que ficaria muito ruim o texto todo aqui, vou adicionar o enunciado.

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma implementação do exercício:

```
#include <algorithm>  
#include <array>   
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 5> notas;
    std::generate(notas.begin(), notas.end(), [] {
        double nota;
        std::cin >> nota;
        return nota;
    });

    decltype(notas)::iterator menor_nota, maior_nota;
    std::tie(menor_nota, maior_nota) = std::minmax_element(notas.begin(), notas.end());

    std::iter_swap(menor_nota, notas.end() - 2);
    std::iter_swap(maior_nota, notas.end() - 1);

    double soma_notas = std::accumulate(notas.begin(), notas.end() - 2, 0.0);

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << soma_notas;

    return 0;
}
```

Aqui estou usando a C++ Standard Library para fazer absolutamente tudo, mas você pode - e, do ponto de vista de aprendizado, deve - reimplementar essas algoritmos manualmente usando laços e lógica simples.

#### Lógica do algoritmo:

1. Leia todos os elementos para um *container* (`array`, `vector`, etc)
2. Encontre a maior e a menor nota
3. Remova (ou no caso, mova para o final do *container*) os elementos encontrados
4. Some os elementos restantes
5. Imprima o resultado formatado corretamente

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou estudar esse código e implementar ele. Grato pela ajuda.